# Существуют ли в одном слове признаки сказуемого и обстоятельства?

Tags: члены-предложения

Например, в предложении "Москва-река широка" Москва-река и сказуемое, и определение. Но слово это составное. Хочется найти такое предложение, где одно слово играло бы сразу две роли: сказуемого и обстоятельства.
Хотелось бы увидеть пример.

Буду благодарен примерам и других сочетаний ролей членов предложения.

Comment: _b10s: Например, в предложении "Москва-река широка" **Москва-река** и сказуемое, и определение._ === ??? По-моему, **Москва-река** в этом предложении не сказуемое, а подлежащее. Сказуемое же -- **широка**.

Answer (score 1):

Москва-река широка. Здесь именная часть составного сказуемого выражена кратким прилагательным.

**В то же время в качестве именной части сказуемого** могут использоваться различные слова, словосочетания и обороты, **в том числе с обстоятельственным значением.**

Примеры.  На улице стало темно (наречие). Здесь всё стало по-другому (наречие).

Всё небо в тучах (падежная форма существительного с обстоятельственным значением).

Сравнить: Солнце скрылось(где?)  в тучах (здесь простое сказуемое и обстоятельство).

Вывод: Одно и то же слово не может быть одновременно сказуемым и обстоятельством, но в именную часть сказуемого могут входить слова с обстоятельственным значением.

Answer (score 1):

Это синкретичные члены предложения, часто с эллипсисом сказуемого:

*Барыш **пополам**.*

Сказуемое пропущено, но его роль играет наречие "пополам", отвечающее на вопрос обстоятельства  как? Выходит, что это и обстоятельство, и сказуемое.

*Ветеран Черноморского пароходства по-прежнему **в строю**.*

Эллипсис сказуемого(находится), его роль играет обстоятельство места "в строю"

http://literary.ru/literary.ru/readme.php?archive=1206184486&id=1206018568&subaction=showfull

По семантике члены предложения делятся на однозначные (типичные) и многозначные (синкретичные). Синкретизм членов предложения обусловлен рядом факторов, среди которых основными являются употребление неморфологизованных членов предложения, двойные синтаксические связи и отношения, синкретичные категориальные значения членов предложения, эллипсис глагольной формы и др.:

*Мама была отсюда, из этого поселка, выросла здесь, а папа городской (В. Распутин).*

Однозначные сказуемые — выросла и городской (форма соответствует содержанию) — это морфологизованные сказуемые. Неморфологизованные сказуемые — была отсюда и из поселка. Сказуемостную функцию этих словоформ подчеркивают типичное сказуемое выросла и антонимичное городской. Дополнительные семантические компоненты (значения обстоятельства места) привносятся в эти сказуемые лексико-грамматическими свойствами именной части. Словоформа из поселка уточняет семантику наречия отсюда. Таким образом, эти неморфологизованные сказуемые по своей семантике синкретичны: совмещают значения сказуемого и обстоятельства места.

*Я буду **здесь** и буду злиться,я буду верен до конца(С.Чекмарёв)*

Буду злиться и буду верен - однозначно сказуемые, а  **здесь** - синкретичный член, совмещающий значение присвязочного сказуемого(буду здесь) и обстоятельства места